# How to post on a page in a wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a website using wordpress. I have a page called home. Now I need to post some content on my page(home). How can I do that? 
Advance thanks.

Comment: Are you new in Wordpress and php

Comment: Yes I am new to wordpress.. I know some more in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study https://codex.wordpress.org/File:stepOneRead.png

Read Step 4. Creating Your First Blog Post

- [how-to-add-a-new-post-in-wordpress-and-utilize-all-the-features](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-a-new-post-in-wordpress-and-utilize-all-the-features/)
- [what-is-the-difference-between-posts-vs-pages-in-wordpress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-is-the-difference-between-posts-vs-pages-in-wordpress/)
- [learn.wordpress.com -- bonus-round-get-a-home-page](https://learn.wordpress.com/bonus-round-get-a-home-page/)